# Show that $f \in c_0^*$ and $||f||=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $$\begin{eqnarray}
f: c_0 & \to & \mathbb{R}\\
  (x_i)_1^{\infty} & \to & \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_j}{j!}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
Show that $f \in c_0^*$ and $||f||=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}$.

I can show that $f \in c_0^*$ but can't show the restant.
$c_0=(x_i)_1^{\infty} \ ; \ x_i \to 0, \ n \to \infty$

Comment: I take it you're using the infinity norm on $c_0$?

Comment: yes... i can show that $||f|| \leq \sum...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$||f(x_i)||=\left|\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_j}{j!}\right|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x_j|}{j!} \leq ||(x_i)||_\infty \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!} $$
so we have
$$||f||\leq  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}$$
Now let $(x^k_i)$ defined by $x_1=\cdots,x_k=1$ and $x_i=0$ if $i>k$ so $||(x^k_i)||_\infty=1$ and then
$$\frac{|f(x^k_i)|}{||(x^k_i)||_\infty}=\sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{j!}\leq ||f||$$
and pass to the limit $k\to \infty$.

Comment: this one convinced me! kkk thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $\mathbf{x}:=(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is in $c_0$. Then
$$
\lvert x_n\rvert\leq\sup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\,\lvert x_m\rvert=\|\mathbf{x}\|\tag{1}
$$
for all $n$. So, if you start with
$$
\left\lvert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{n!}\right\rvert\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lvert x_n\rvert}{n!},
$$
and apply (1), you immediately get that
$$
\|f\|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}.
$$
So, what remains is to show that this is the best upper bound. To do this, it suffices to consider only $\mathbf{x}\in c_0$ such that $\|\mathbf{x}\|=1$. Try thinking about the sequence of elements $\mathbf{x}^{(j)}\in c_0$ given by
$$
x_n^{(j)}=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $n\leq j$}\\ 0 &\text{else}\end{cases},
$$
where $x_n^{(j)}$ denotes the $n$th element of $\mathbf{x}^{(j)}$.

Comment: why taking $x$, $||x||=1$ it is suficienty? thanks

Comment: Well, with the operator norm, $\|x\|=1$ is always sufficient.  It can be proved using linearity.  Here, that's not even necessary - we can consider any sequences that we want to when trying to establish the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$
\vert f(x)\vert\leq\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left\vert\frac{x_j}{j!}\right\vert\leq\sup_j\vert x_j\vert\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j!}
$$

Then, consider sequences of the form $(x_j)=(1,1,1,\ldots,0,0,\ldots)$, and send the ones off to infinity; this sequence of sequences will have $\vert f(x)\vert\rightarrow\sum_{j=1}^\infty 1/j!$

Comment: it is one of inequalitys...thank you

Comment: @icurays1 The sequence you describe isn't actually in $c_0$.

Comment: Yep, I forgot that $c_0$ is "compactly supported" sequences.  Edited...thanks @nrpeterson

Comment: @icurays1 I think it is common to use $c_0$ for sequences converging to zero, rather than those with compact (i.e., finite) support. (This is so in the question, too.) The latter space is sometimes denoted $c_{00}$.